# How to add terminal zeroes after rounding

Tags: java, rounding

I'm trying to round to a different number of decimal places each time the user says so. I've been trying

```
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(input).setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

(and `ROUND_HALF_UP`, and then doing`dec.doubleValue()`) but it doesn't add terminal zeroes.

For example, 0.4595 becomes 0.46, not 0.460. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well what is the value of `places`? I've just tested it, and with `places` set to 3, that gives 0.460...

Comment: @JonSkeet - I think that it is `dec.doubleValue()` which is trimming out the trailing zeroes. The `BigDecimal` object `dec` would print the value just fine, as you said. :)

Comment: I also set places to 3...and now it's giving me 0.459!

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: Ah yes, I hadn't noticed the use of `doubleValue()`...

Comment: Could someone please upload a sample of their code? I am very confused, because I think I am doing the same thing everyone else is... I am just doing what I posted above, and yet now it returns 0.459..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you call `doubleValue()`? Just avoid doing that. There are two problems with it:

- A `double` has no notion of trailing zeroes, unlike `BigDecimal`
- Converting between `double` and `BigDecimal` (in either direction) is almost always a bad idea. They're generally used for different *kinds* of values - e.g. physical dimensions like height and weight are best for `double`; artificial values such as currency are best for `BigDecimal`

Without the call to `doubleValue()` you're fine:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "0.4595";
        int places = 3;
        BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(input)
            .setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(dec); // Prints 0.460
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. This is very strange. I am doing the exact same thing - only inside a method. That is the only difference. And yet I still get 0.459. Does anyone have a hypothesis as to why that might be so?

Comment: @howAnAngel_Dies_: I strongly suspect you don't have *exactly* the same thing - and my code is within a method as well (the `main` method). If you can show us your *exact* code which is failing (currently we don't even know the type of `input`, for example) then we'd be more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(input).setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```